# Appsync authentification with public / private access without AWS Incognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I struggle here with understanding about how to secure my Amplify / Appsync application  without using AWS Incognito Pools.

I am using an API key for now for connecting from my public apps and from a secured Backoffice. But I still would like to protect my app and users from calling certain queries, mutations etc.

I know that [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth/#auth) allow to use an @auth mode but how can I use it ?
How would it work knowing that I would make direct graphql calls from my public app and nodejs graphql calls from my lambdas from my backoffice.

Any guidance here would be super welcome, thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out how to do things here, in case it might help others.

Ftrst of all, we can use IAM without AWS cognito.

I had to:

- set up IAM as a default authorization from my Appsync app (AWS service)
- set up the rules on the schema graphql:
  such as:

[image]

so now I can use an API key front-wise and IAM from my AWS Lam